# my content is flowing out of its container's height

Tags: html, css

i have this markup which i gave a background color, but the contents just flow out of the background color, even though i gave it  height of 100% and a min-height too.

```css
.nav {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav li {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <ul class="nav dark-grey">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am just trying to build without a framework, please can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the height of `.nav` to `auto` instead of `40px`, and that should allow it to consume required space.

```css
.nav {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav li {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <ul class="nav dark-grey">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are forcing the height to use height: 40px you need to use min-height:40px;

see fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bf6nLmL6/

```
          .nav  {
                  padding: 0;
                  display: flex;
                  flex-wrap: nowrap;
                  flex-direction: column;
                  justify-content: flex-start;
                  align-items: flex-start;
                  min-height: 40px;
                  list-style: none;
                  border: 1px solid red;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have update the CSS, please check:

```css
.nav {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav li {
  padding: 8px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <ul class="nav dark-grey">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Second option:

```css
.nav {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav li {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <ul class="nav dark-grey">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change :**

```
.nav {
    height: 40px;
    //other codes...
}
```

**To :**

```
.nav {
    height: auto;
    //other codes...
}
```

```css
.nav {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav li {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <ul class="nav dark-grey">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```